# How to keep tracking of a new cell appearing in the tableView in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, chatbot, text-to-speech

In my application, I have created a ChatBot which is responsible for interacting with the user, it is asking 5 Questions, and when a new Q is being asked, the question appears and there is a speech method that speeches the question to the user, but, every time that it is going to speak the question, it starts from the first question to speech, dunno where to put my method to speech the new question, not starting from the first one, anyone has an idea?
I want, when the new cell from the left appears, it has the Q inside the cell, I add a method textToSpeech() method to say the Q for the user when the 2nd or 3rd or ... Q appears, it doesn't speak the new Q, it starts from the first Q.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly your question, but if just want to know when a cell is going to be displayed inside a UITableView you can just register a class as a delegate of the table view and implement for those two methods:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
       didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```